# What gave "terrific" a positive connotation?

Tags: etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How and why have some words changed to a complete opposite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22293/how-and-why-have-some-words-changed-to-a-complete-opposite)

I have noticed that:

- *horrible* means bad
- *terrible* means bad
- *horrific* means bad

So why does *terrific* mean good?

Comment: I think you meant for  your question title to read "what gave **'terrific'** a positive connotation", then.

Comment: And by the same token, why does *awful* mean bad?

Comment: While this is indeed a duplicate (of several other questions, actually), at least it was asked with flair!

Comment: Well, now that the picture is gone and replaced by (amazingly boring) verbiage, my previous comment no longer holds. :(  (Well, the original asker *did* ask it with flair, but the question as shown on this site no longer reflects that.)

Comment: Renan, is that picture still up on the Web somewhere?  If so, could you provide a link?

Comment: @John Y Here you go. http://i.stack.imgur.com/5lRSd.jpg

Comment: @JohnY: You could click the link **edited [Aug 21 at 14:49](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/38606/revisions)** provided in the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The meaning of *terrific* has actually changed over time. According to [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=terrific):

> 1660s, "frightening," from L. terrificus "causing terror or fear," from terrere "fill with fear" (see terrible) + root of facere "to make" (see factitious). Weakened sensed of "very great, severe" (e.g. terrific headache) appeared 1809; colloquial sense of "excellent" began 1888.

So *terrific* started out on the same lines as *horrific*, but then gained a positive colloquial sense in the late 1800s. The phenomenon in which a previously bad word takes on a good connotation is discussed [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=149436), in which it is called [amelioration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelioration).

Amelioration (which has occurred for *terrific*, *wicked*, *luxury*) is a type of [semantic change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change). While it is unclear what precisely happened to *terrific*, there are a few ways in which this change can occur:

> - Linguistic forces
> - Psychological forces
> - Sociocultural forces
> - Cultural/encyclopedic forces

You can read more about it [here](http://courses.nus.edu.sg/course/elltankw/history/Vocab/C.htm). It has been suggested (though there is little proof) that *terrific* became "good" because of an association with the popular media via *King Kong*. Other than this theory, though, it is clear that *terrific* underwent some kind of semantic change between the late 1800s and early 1900s. In 1930 [Popular Science](http://books.google.com/books?id=tCgDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA35&dq=%22terrific%22&hl=en&ei=mc5OToyAL4fiiAKTh4mKAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22terrific%22&f=false) was still using the term to mean something "frightening", and by [the 1940s](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22terrific%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1931,cd_max:1944&lr=lang_en#q=%22terrific%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1931,cd_max:1944,lr%3alang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=-c5OTqaCKJTWiAK8y62UAQ&ved=0CCAQpwUoAQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=d124ba368e543b57&biw=1366&bih=667) it was used mostly to mean "good".

Comment: Has "awful" been ameliorated?  It was certainly pejorated first (Christopher Wren iirc described St Paul's as awful -- in the good way), going from "awe-inspiring" to "very bad", and it's gone up, just a bit, to mean "very" in some contexts.

Comment: @Malvolio Edited to use "luxury" instead. I was just pulling examples of semantic change, but not the right ones

Comment: @simchona The answer in this duplicate question is a lot better than that of the original. It's a pity it had to be closed. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @Malvolio As I understand it, amelioration in this context refers to movement from a negative connotation to a positive connotation. If there was some change in connotation with "awful" as you are suggesting, I'm not sure it would be called amelioration, since the change would be from a positive connotation to a negative one. Maybe there is another term for that opposite movement?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee -- exactly my point.  "Awful" started out positive, meaning "awe-inspiring", and then declined sharply (the opposite of amelioration is "perjoration").  It has ameliorated _a little_ lately.  For some reason, the adverb form either never perjorated, or ameliorated before I was born, because if you say something is "awfully nice", you mean that it is very nice indeed.