# Reversal in word meaning

Tags: word-usage

Are there any words that were pejorative but are now used in a positive way?  Obviously, there are slang words that have changed meaning, but are there any others?

Comment: How about *nice*?

Comment: Many of the terms used to refer to a "toilet" have swapped sides several times.  And there's a Greek school of philosophy that reportedly swapped meanings 180 degrees (due to ironic use of the term), but I can't remember what it is just now.

Comment: Man, that question is _baaad_! I mean really _wicked_!

Comment: Related: **1**. [How often do words change meaning then revert back to their original meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18195/how-often-do-words-change-meaning-then-revert-back-to-their-original-meaning?lq=1) **2**. [Why the opposite meanings of the word “bollocks”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/why-the-opposite-meanings-of-the-word-bollocks) **3.** [How did “s***” and “the s***” come to mean opposite things?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230399/how-did-s-and-the-s-come-to-mean-opposite-things?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The word 'nice' is a good example of this. It comes from the latin word nescire (not knowing): in the middle ages it used to mean ignorant or stupid. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nice.

Comment: Although this may, to a certain extent, be swinging back the other way: when a woman describes a man as "nice", she often means that he's boring.

Answer (score 0):

*Fulsome* has gone back and forth.

The earliest meaning (obsolete) in the OED is " Characterized by abundance, possessing or affording copious supply; abundant, plentiful, full."

All but one of the remaning meanings given are negative, in the sense of (at least) excessive, even the only one given as current (in 1898 when the entry was last revised): " Of language, style, behaviour, etc.: Offensive to good taste; esp. offending from excess or want of measure or from being ‘over-done’. Now chiefly used in reference to gross or excessive flattery, over-demonstrative affection, or the like."

Since 1898 it has largely lost the negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean words like "sick" and "wicked" that were negative, but are now used to describe positive things?